# Why does my two-dimensional array print out incorrect values?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print the sum of columns 1, 4 and 6.
When I input 30 one's into my 2d array this is what I get as result:

```
Sum of 1st column is: 6
Sum of 1st column is: 12
Sum of 1st column is: 18
Sum of 1st column is: 24
Sum of 1st column is: 30
Sum of 4th column: 3
Sum of 4th column: 6
Sum of 4th column: 9
Sum of 4th column: 12
Sum of 4th column: 15
Sum of 6th column is: 1
Sum of 6th column is: 2
Sum of 6th column is: 3
Sum of 6th column is: 4
Sum of 6th column is: 5
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, sum1=0, sum2=0, sum3=0, arr[5][6];
    int value;

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j=0; j<6; j++){
            printf("Enter a value: ");
            scanf("%d",&value);
            arr[i][j]=value;
        }
    }

    printf("Two Dimensional array elements:\n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
      for(j=0;j<6;j++) {
         printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
         if(j==5){
            printf("\n");
         }
       }
    }

    //this functions calculate the sum of the 1st column//
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=0; j<6; j++){
            sum1 = arr[i][j] + sum1;
        }
        printf("Sum of 1st column is: %d\n", sum1);
    }

    //this functions calculate the sum of the 4th column//
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=3; j<6; j++){
            sum2 = arr[i][j] + sum2;
        }
        printf("Sum of 4th column: %d\n", sum2);
    }

    //this functions calculate the sum of the 6th column//
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=5; j<6; j++){
            sum3 = arr[i][j] + sum3;
        }
        printf("Sum of 6th column is: %d\n", sum3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The sum of the 1st column is `arr[0][0] + arr[1][0] + arr[2][0] + arr[3][0] + arr[4][0]`

Comment: Review `for(j=3; j<6; j++){`

Comment: try this; put  different number in each cell and you will see where you went wrong.

Comment: Instead of writing `x = x + y` you can write `x += y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your printfs, I'm assuming you want to print the sums of *columns* 1, 4, and 6.

Let's just think about column 0 for simplicity - you can easily extend this.

You have a 2D array, and you want the sum of the numbers in column 0. Think about how you'd traverse your array iteratively to accomplish this. You want to keep your column fixed at 0, and just increment through your rows - does that make sense?

Here is one of many ways to do this:

```
//this functions calculate the sum of the 1st column//
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    sum1 = arr[i][0] + sum1;
    }
printf("Sum of 1st column is: %d\n", sum1);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank guys for your support and help, but the program still tends to produce the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, StoneThrow has already stated the cause, but there appears to be an error on the code regarding the loops, for example, in the first loop for adding the first column, you are actually adding the whole matrix since you're incrementing the number for the rows as well as for the column.

Code should go something like this:

```
//Addition for column one
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    sum1=arr[i][0]+sum1;
    printf("Sum of 1st column is: %d\n", sum1);
}

//Addition for column four
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    sum2=arr[i][3]+sum2;
    printf("Sum of the 4th column is: %d\n", sum2);
}

//Addition for column six
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    sum3=arr[i][5]+sum3;
    printf("Sum of the 6th column is: %d\n", sum3);
}
```

So, just watch out with the looping, these don't need to be nested since you're actually just using one of the array's groups as a variable, and the other one as a constant.